# Is $[0,5]$ open in $[-5,5]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm writing examples about relatively open sets. Can an open subset $U\subset\Bbb{R}$ be found such that $[0,5]=U \cap[-5,5]$, or is this maybe a nonsensical question because of some theorem?

Comment: It is not open. In particular, the point $0$ is not an interior point of $[0,5]$ in $[-5,5]$.

Comment: In fact $[0,5]$ is closed in $[-5,5]$.

Comment: But $(0,5]$ is open in $[-5,5]$

Comment: Nope.  $0$ is not an interior point. But it is open in $[-5,-1]\cup [0,5]$ and in *that* set $0$ *is* an interior point. The is not at all a nonsensical theorem and there is not theorem I'm aware of...I suppose we can generalize for a set that doesn't seem like it *should* be open to actually be open in a larger set, the points that seem like they shouldn't be interior point must be end (or isolated) points of the larger set.  $0$ and $5$ are the "problem points" to solve the problem the large set can't have anything on the "other side" of $5$ or $0$. That's the only way to make them interior.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I misread your question.  To be open then the set $S = U\cap [-5,5]$ must contain $0$ (and all $x; 0 < x \le 5$) but must not contain any $(-\epsilon,0)$ for some $\epsilon$ (else every open neighborhood of $0$ we contain a few negative values and $0$ wouldn't be interior).  But for there to be a set $U$ where that is true $0\in U$ but $0$ can't be an interior point of $U$ (else such an $\epsilon$ will exist) so $U$ can't be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear with me

we want  $[0,5] \subset U\cap [-5,5]$. So that would mean $[0,5]\subset U$ and $0 \in U$.

And we want $U$ to be open in $\mathbb R$.  That would mean $0$ is interior point, or that there is some  $\epsilon > 0$ so that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\subset U$. If we let $\rho = \min(\epsilon, 5)$ then $(-\rho, \rho) \subset (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset U$.  And $(-\rho,\rho)\subset U\cap [-5,5]$.

And finally we also want $[0,5]$ to be open in $U\cap [-5,5]$.  But that means $0$ is an interior point of $[0,5]$ in $U\cap [-5,5]$  which means there is an $\omega>0$ so that $(-\omega,\omega)\cap [U\cap[-5,5]]$ is a subset of $[0,5]$.

But $(-\omega,0) \not \subset [0,5]$.  In fact $(-\omega,0)$ is disjoint from $[0,5]$.  So to have  $(-\omega,\omega)\cap [U\cap[-5,5]]\subset [0,5]$ we must have $[0,\omega)\subset U$ but $(-\omega,0)$ disjoint from $U$.

And that assures that $U$ is *not* open in $\mathbb R$ (because $(-\rho, \rho) \not \subset U$ after all!)

So it's possible to find *a* set $U$ where $[0,5]$ is open in $U\cap [-5,5]$ (all we need is that some $(-\omega,0)$ be disjoint from $U$ while $[0,5]\subset U$) but such a set can never be open in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is made by open intervals (basis for the euclidean topology) and there is no way to intersect an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-5,5]$ such that $[0,5]$ is open in the subspace topology. $[0,5]$ is a closed set (easy to verify) and indeed it cannot be open otherwise you would reach the contradiction of having $[-5,5]$ a disconnected space.

Comment: $[-5,0)$ is open in $[-5,5]$ but not in $\mathbb R$. So, open interval in $\mathbb R$ may be not open in $[-5,0)$.

Comment: For the relative topology you intersect [-5,5] with open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. You misunderstood.  There is no way to get [0,5] intersecting [-5,5] and an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. There is no point in downgrading @Surb

Comment: " There is no way to get [0,5] intersecting [-5,5] and an open set of R"  Intuitively this is so. but proving it isn't obvious.  Maybe some explanaiton why not is in order.

Comment: I see your point, and it is clear, but you can easily answer the question of [0,5] not being open with a contradiction using a connectedness argument.